# Located vs Situated

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here are three sentences:

1. The diner was located on a deserted road.
2. His new apartment is located in an exclusive part of town.
3. We arrived at a cemetery located at the edge of the city.

Questions:

Is "located" natural in all three sentences? Would using "situated" be equally natural?

Comment: locate is to location as situate is to situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the answers in the EL&U question [“Situated” vs. “located”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/situated-vs-located#:%7E:text=The%20two%20words%20can%20be,than%20just%20to%20an%20address.&text=Located%20would%20work%20with%20the,sound%20stilted%20in%20the%20first.) for more information on when to use *situated* vs *located* and the differences between them.

> Would using "situated" be equally natural?

For a native English speaker, at least in the U.S. where I am from, you're more likely to here someone use "located" in your example sentences.  So from that standpoint, it would be more natural.  It is not *wrong* to use "situated" in these sentences.

Also, possibly more common:

1. The diner was on a deserted road.
2. His new apartment is in an exclusive part of town.

For the third sentence, you should keep "located" because it provides distance between the two "at"s.

Comment: @choster thanks for the edits, I sometimes slip into old habits of calling the USA "America" even though it is ambiguous everywhere other than here.

Comment: I actually find the usage of "America" meaning the United States to be much more prevalent in news media in the UK, Australasia, and Africa than in U.S.-based media, but this being the Internet, there is always someone who interjects that *America refers to the entire world besides Slobovia, not just one country, you arrogant Yanks* and it's exasperating.

Comment: @choster good to know!  I have heard similar remarks, so I try to stay away from it now just to be safe.